# How to make an Abp.Dapper multiple-table query?

Tags: dapper, aspnetboilerplate

I have an entity model `Person -> Phones(collection)` and the following code

**Person**

```
[Table("PbPersons")]
public class Person: FullAuditedEntity, IMustHaveTenant
{
    public const int MaxNameLength = 32;
    public const int MaxSurnameLength = 32;
    public const int MaxEmailAddressLength = 255;

    public virtual int TenantId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(MaxNameLength)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(MaxSurnameLength)]
    public virtual string Surname { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(MaxEmailAddressLength)]
    public virtual string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

}
```

**Phones**

```
[Table("PbPhones")]
public class Phone : CreationAuditedEntity<long>
{
    public const int MaxNumberLength = 16;

    [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual int PersonId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual PhoneType Type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(MaxNumberLength)]
    public virtual string Number { get; set; }

}
```

**Old Application Tier with Abp.EF**

This code returns a list of persons including phones

```
using Abp.Application.Services.Dto;
using Abp.Authorization;
using Abp.Dapper.Repositories;
using Abp.Domain.Repositories;
using Abp.Extensions;
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class PersonAppService : WebAppServiceBase, IPersonAppService
{
private readonly IRepository<Person> _personRepository;
private readonly IRepository<Phone, long> _phoneRepository;

public PersonAppService(IRepository<Person> personRepository, 
IRepository<Phone, long> phoneRepository)        
{
    _personRepository = personRepository;
    _phoneRepository = phoneRepository;
}

 public ListResultDto<PersonListDto> GetPeople(GetPeopleInput input)
{

            var persons = _personRepository
            .GetAll()
            .Include(p => p.Phones)
            .WhereIf(
                !input.Filter.IsNullOrEmpty(),
                p => p.Name.Contains(input.Filter) ||
                        p.Surname.Contains(input.Filter) ||
                        p.EmailAddress.Contains(input.Filter)
            )
            .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
            .ThenBy(p => p.Surname)
            .ToList();

            return new ListResultDto<PersonListDto>(Mapper.Map<List<Person>, List<PersonListDto>>(persons));
}
```

}

**New Application Tier with Abp.Dapper**

However when I use Abp.Dapper the GetAll method does not allow to include any method like Include/WhereIf, I know that is because it implements IEnumerable interface. I need that also returns the list of phones for each Person. What should I do?, I tried with linq (include, it is not available) with not success.

```
 using Abp.Application.Services.Dto;
 using Abp.Authorization;
 using Abp.Dapper.Repositories;
 using Abp.Domain.Repositories;
 using Abp.Extensions;
 using AutoMapper;
 using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;

 public class PersonAppService : WebAppServiceBase, IPersonAppService
 {
private readonly IDapperRepository<Person> _personRepository;
private readonly IRepository<Phone, long> _phoneRepository;

public PersonAppService(IDapperRepository<Person> personRepository, 
IRepository<Phone, long> phoneRepository)        
{
    _personRepository = personRepository;
    _phoneRepository = phoneRepository;
}

 public ListResultDto<PersonListDto> GetPeople(GetPeopleInput input)
{

            var persons = _personRepository.GetAll()              
            .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
            .ThenBy(p => p.Surname)
            .ToList();

            return new ListResultDto<PersonListDto>(Mapper.Map<List<Person>, List<PersonListDto>>(persons));
}
```

}

Comment: Please, provide some code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Thank you both, I have edited my question, hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

See the test code that fetches the navigation data as well.

```
 public async Task Should_Include_Navigation_Properties_If_Requested()
        {
            using (var uow = _uowManager.Begin())
            {
                var post = await _postRepository.GetAllIncluding(p => p.Blog).FirstAsync();

                post.Blog.ShouldNotBeNull();
                post.Blog.Name.ShouldBe("test-blog-1");

                await uow.CompleteAsync();
            }
}
```

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/test/Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Tests/Tests/Repository_Tests.cs#L80